# Deep machine learning to improve satellite spatial resolution

Tags: raster, resolution, machine-learning

Are there currently technologies based on deep machine learning that can improve the spatial resolution of satellite images (e.g. Sentinel-2)?

An example of the use of such technology to reconstruct a [photograph of a person's face](https://ai.googleblog.com/2021/07/high-fidelity-image-generation-using.html):

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Do not know about deep learning methods for improving spatial resolution, yet based on [this](https://www.mdpi.com/2504-3900/2/7/345#:%7E:text=Pan%20Sharpening%20is%20an%20important,program%20for%20Earth%20observation%20studies.) research, one is able to use a band from **visible spectrum** or **NIR** band from Sentinel-2 as *panchromatic* band, with *pan-sharpen* method in order to obtain multispectral imagery with spatial resolution up to 10 meters.